# Is there any way to compare the the data in my database table with the excel file in the system

Tags: php

I am making an system where we read the excel ,csv  format files. And there are columns like country code and cities codes, and countries has only one value and cities may be comma separated like

Country Code         CityCode

230                           91, 92, 01-03, 1-3

There are many rows like this in my database .
And my final output should be

Final code     CountryCode    City Code

23091            230                  91

23092           230                  92

23001          230                   01

23002          230                  02

23003          230                  03

2301            230                  1

2302            230                  2

2303            230                  3

**And i am getting the right output like above. And moving the uploaded files in a directory on my server.**

I am using the library given on 
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

**I am using this function to get range of codes like 01-03 and 1-3 is as follows**

```
function getRangeOfCodes($mystring)

    {

                     $findme   = '-';

         $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

         if($pos === false)
         {
             $length   = strlen($mystring);
             $range    = range(preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$mystring),preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$mystring));
         }
         else
         {
             $ct       = explode("-",$mystring);
             $length   = strlen($ct[0]);
             $range    = range(preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$ct[0]), preg_replace("/[^0-9]+/", "",$ct[1]));
         }

         $result['range']  = $range;
         $result['length'] = $length;
         return $result;
    }
```

**By mistake i was making change in the files and forgot to trim the codes and with space the city codes were read as**

Final code           CountryCode           City Code

23091                      230                      91

230092                      230                      092

230001                      230                         001

230002                      230                      002

230003                      230                         003

23001                      230                          01

23002                      230                          02

23003                      230                          03

So is there any way so that while downloading these code from database  i can compare it with the uploaded sheet in the directory by giving path of it so that if a city code does not match with the city code corresponding to the country code , then i can display an error for that.

**May be i am asking a wrong or infeasible question. But i want to be sure about my output. So can any one can help me if this is possible then what should me the standard way to do that.**

Answer (score 1):

IMO It is possible but a wrong approach to solve the problem. If you can read the excel then you can directly output from it. Why put it in database then? Secondly your database table is not normalized.

If you have the excel sheet then upload it correctly. Double check is not worth it.

Comment: Hi Subir thanks for your reply, but the thing is that i will upload the file into database once and get the out number of times if want later on. And also can you please explain about the table is not normalised